# Can't access through localhost to my web server on docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am following this tutorial to achieve a dockerized django app:

http://ruddra.com/2016/08/14/docker-django-nginx-postgres/

I am able to build and run the docker image and conatiner without problem.

For example my services from container are in these status:

```
docker ps
```

[image]

```
docker-compose logs web
```

[image]

`docker-compose logs` nginx returs nothing

`Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /config
ADD /config/requirements.pip /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.pip
RUN mkdir /src;
WORKDIR /src
```

`docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dg01
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn helloworld_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: ps01
```

`helloworld_project` is:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}
```

`requirements.pip` is

```
Django==2.0.5
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
```

And all the project structure is:

[image]

Why `localhost:8000` and/or `localhost:80`  run with mozilla firefox says the connection is restarted and I am not able to view the app?

Answer (score 1):

Working!

The solution was to redirect my `8001 host port` to the `8000 docker port`. Probably my laptop was using this port. The same thing happened for `5432 postgreSQL port`.

In Winwdos is also working with `docker toolbox` but to connect throug browser is recommended to use `Kitematic` (software tool that comes by default with docker toolbox) because it allows to connect quickly to the `docker web server IP`. In windows `docker` runs in a `VirtualBox`, so you can not connect using `localhost`, because it redirects to the virtual machine and not to the container running on this `VM`.

Comment: I know this was written a while back but can't thank you enough! Kudos!